# Loading/Downloading a URL with a space followed by a number

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I have a few files I'm trying to download in the following format:

```
http://someserver.com/movie_title 5.1.12.mov
```

When I place the following code on it:

```
mediaURL =[[mediaURL stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I get the following result:

```
http://someserver.com/movie_title%205.1.12.mov
```

If I copy paste that into my browser on any machine, it downloads correctly. However, It won't download as an NSURL on my project; it just fails.

Any suggestions? I'm guessing it's something silly that I'm forgetting.

Comment: Does it work if you create the NSURL using an nsstring containing hard-coded "http://someserver.com/movie_title%205.1.12.mov" ?

Comment: @ade no it still does not work

Comment: @kevinl what does the console log show for the operation?

Comment: Can I suggest you share complete code showing how you create and use your NSURL object? Given that you're downloading video data I'm assuming you are using dataWithContentsOfURL to download the data and write it out to a file in the documents directory ? use one of the methods with an error output such as dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error

Comment: Just replace the occurrence of the string like below NSString *str = @"http://someserver.com/movie_title 5.1.12.mov";
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];

Answer (score 1):

- If I were you I would confirm that the escaping is the problem, it could be some other part of your code that is failing (if you have access to the server manually rename the file with only characters.mov)
- If you try this and it works, make sure you are using the expected headers and http method (POST or GET).
- Else please put the code on git so we can download it and figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the server that the video was coming from did not support streaming capabilities. I tried putting the same link on my safari browser and the item did not stream.

Thanks everyone